# Macbook Pro REALLY slow with bootcamp win xp and SSD

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, ssd

I have a Macbook Pro and installed a new solid state drive (SSD) the Mac side runs great but I also installed Windows XP pro on a bootcamp partition and it has became unbearably slow. When I type at time is freezes for several seconds and there are several other random delays. Anyone hove any ideas what I can specifically tweak to get performance back?

Comment: There could be many causes - the most obvious (and hopefully the easiest to fix) is that a program is causing the performance issues. Have you inspected the Task Manager to see which applications are monopolising the CPU, or have high memory usage, or have a high number of page faults, etc.?

Comment: Apple doesn't have the best Windows drivers in the world. I had a lot of performance issues (up to the point where my 1.86ghz solo-core was out-performing it. It had display resolution issues, and worst of all the DVI-VGA adapter wasn't working. I decided to switch to that 1.86ghz solo-core computer and I'm happy with it and it runs Windows 7 perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with the comment above that it's probably a driver issue. Once you've installed the provided Boot Camp drivers off the Apple disc, it's worth updating them specifically from the manufacturer. In my case, with an aluminum MacBook (Late 2008), I found getting the drivers for the Nvidia 9400M graphics chip [straight from Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) made a performance difference.

As an aside, I find it frustrating to figure out what causes those intermittent pauses since it could really be anything.